# Cmd with no message in Elm

Tags: elm, feedback, no-op

Is it possible to create a `Cmd` that sends no message on completion in Elm?

Specifically, I am trying to have an element grab the focus (programmically), but I don't need to be informed of the result:

```
Dom.focus "element-id"
    |> Task.attempt FocusReceived
...
FocusReceived result ->
    model ! []  -- result ignored
```

Is there any way to just have the Elm "engine" not send a message after this `Cmd`?

I know that my code (`FocusReceived result -> model ! []`) is a no-op, but I would like the message not to be sent at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, a `Msg` is always required. It is a common idiom in typical Elm projects to include a `Msg` type constructor that does nothing named `NoOp`.

```elm
type Msg
    = NoOp
    | ...
```

The `update` function does what `FocusReceived` in your example does, namely, nothing.

```elm
case msg of
    NoOp ->
        model ! []
    ...
```

Comment: That is what I suspected. In my case, I am going to have the main `update` function also trigger a command to save the state to outside storage, so I wanted a way to ignore commands that have no effect on the state. Thanks.